# Disable class template member for void types?

Tags: c++, templates, void, sfinae

Considering the following basic class template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename T >
class A {
 public:
    A() = default;

    T obj;

    template < typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_void< U >::value >::type >
    T& get();
};
```

I'm using `<type_traits>` to get a simple SFINAE implementation that hides `get()` if template argument is void.

However, I still get the compiler error for void types `error: forming reference to void`, which I am not sure the reasons for are. Is there anything wrong with the class declaration syntax?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    A<int> b;
    A<void> t;  // error: forming reference to void

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It was pointed out that the issue was that `obj` can't be void. One workaround would be to use a pointer instead:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template < typename T >
class A {
 public:
    A() = default;

    std::shared_ptr< T > obj;

    template < typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_void< U >::value >::type >
    U& get() { return *obj; };
};
```

But I still get the  `error: forming reference to void`, which implies that the compiler is still trying to compile `get()`.

Comment: The problem is not the function declaration, but the member variable `T`. In C++, a variable cannot have the `void` type.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot have `T obj` when `T` is `void` so disabling `get` won't do you any good.

Comment: @Elliott agreed!

Comment: You probably have to write class template specialization for `void`. Can't think of any other way out (unless of course you can change the design to avoid accepting `void` as type).

Comment: Updated my question with a modified code snippet - I still get the same error, seems that there is still something wrong with the get() template declaration.

Comment: Using a pointer is a *very* bad workaround. You are adding an expensive allocation for something that can be easily done without in a multitude of ways. It would not pass code review.

Comment: Use template specialization, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdff84seh).

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3zEvzWsK1) your error with the workaround.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. sure, but I am trying to debug why SFINAE is failing on the `get()` declaration, not how to deal with the data member. On the other hand, template specialization would force me to re-declare anything else I may want to add to `A` , so I am looking for alternative ways to implement this.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. my bad, I was not enabling C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first **problem** is that you are trying to define a variable using

```
T obj;
```

where T is `void`. But according to [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type)

> Any of the following contexts requires type T to be complete:

> definition of an object of type T;

But since `void` is **incomplete type**, you get the error:

> error: 'A::obj' has incomplete type

**Second** we also can't have a return type of `void&` which is why you get the error you mentioned:

> error: forming reference to void

You can **solve** it by:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template < typename T >
class A {
 public:
    A() = default;

    T *obj = nullptr;//note a pointer
    
    template < typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, void>::value,U&>::type get()
    {
        std::cout <<"called"<<std::endl;
        if(obj != nullptr)
        {
           std::cout<<"not null"<<std::endl;
            return *obj;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"null"<<std::endl;
            obj = new T{};
            return *obj;
        }
        
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"destructor called"<<std::endl;
        
        if(!std::is_same<T, void>::value)
        {
            std::cout<<"deleted"<<std::endl;
            delete obj;
            obj = nullptr;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout<<"not deleted"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    A<int> b;
    std::cout<< b.get() <<std::endl;//this will print the string "called" and the integer 0 on console
    std::cout<<"------------------"<<std::endl;
    int &p = b.get();
    std::cout<<"------------------"<<std::endl;
    p = 32;
    std::cout << b.get()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"------------------"<<std::endl;
    
    A<void> t;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Also, don't forget to use `delete` in the destructor.

Comment: Using a pointer as member seems to avoid that issue though (check the question edit), and the compiler still complains about `get()` declaration.

Comment: @joaocandre Read the **second** reason in my answer. You still have `void&` as the return type which is why you get the same error.

Comment: My point is - shouldn't the template declaration  (with `enable_if`) effectively disable `get()` declaration? I know it's an invalid statement, thus why I want the compiler to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way (C++98-compliant even) of resolving this is to write a specialisation of `A`. It it's a big class, it could be annoying though.

Another method is to force `obj` be of some other type than `void`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename T >
class A {
 public:
    A() = default;

    struct empty{};
    [[no_unique_address]]
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, void>, empty, T> obj;

    template <typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void_v<U>>::type>
    U& get() { return obj; }
};

int main()
{
  A<void> v;
  A<int> x;
  int& y = x.get();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3s9c7qrnY).

Comment: If it's a big class you could still write the generic stuff in a separate class and inherit from it for this one.